# How to compare Two general tree's irrespective of the order of children nodes?

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, xml-parsing

I have two general tree's. The identity of that tree is it's root Node pointer. The data structure to represent tree is TreeNode.

```
struct TreeNode{
    int data;
    vector<TreeNode*> subNodes;  // list of pointers to all childNodes of particular Node
    TreeNode* parent;  // pointer to parent Node of this node
}
```

Each tree is identified by it's root Node pointer.
I want to compare Two tree's such that even if the order of child nodes of any two corresponding nodes is different, the `bool compareDeep(TreeNode *root1, TreeNode *root2)` should return true.

Examples to illustrate:
1)
[image]

For this case,
 `bool compareDeep(root1, root2) should return true, as order of child's differs but content is same`

I can compare the Exact equality case, where we can do level order traversal of both tree's at a time, and compare Nodes level by level.

Actually, I am trying to solve this problem with respect to XML tree's, returned by XML parser, where I want to compare two XML DOM tree's irrespective order of elements.

Comment: This is known as tree isomorphism. Here's a detailed explanation in these slides: https://logic.pdmi.ras.ru/~smal/files/smal_jass08_slides.pdf

Comment: Store the nodes in a `std::set<int>` and also keep count of the number of nodes on each level.  A `std::set` automatically sorts the data, so that takes care of the order issue.  Note that this is mostly an algorithms issue, not a C++ language issue -- you would use the same general approach in any other language that supports structures such as `std::set`.

Comment: Given that `std::set` is itself a tree, this looks like a huge overkill.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `std::sort` function to sort pointers and then compare trees, or insert already sorted data

```
bool sortTreeNode(TreeNode* a, TreeNode* b) { return (*a < *b); }

std::sort(subNodes.begin(), subNodes.end(), sortTreeNode);
```

Full comparetion and sort example. In a full version , you need to implement a **copy constructor**, and think about the performance of the code

I defined two functions `sortTreeNode` which sorts each level of subNodes
and `checkLevelTreeNode` compare each level of subNodes

These functions were used with `std::sort` and `std::equal` algorithms

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct TreeNode;
bool sortTreeNode(TreeNode* a, TreeNode* b);
bool checkLevelTreeNode(TreeNode* a, TreeNode* b);

struct TreeNode {
    int data;

    void Print() {
        cout << "{ ";
        for(auto & Current : subNodes) {
            cout << Current->data << " ";
        }
        cout << "}\n";

        for (auto& Current : subNodes) {
            if(Current->subNodes.size())
                Current->Print();
        }
    }

    bool compare(TreeNode& rhs) {
        if (subNodes.size() != rhs.subNodes.size() || data != rhs.data)
            return false;

        sort(subNodes.begin(), subNodes.end(), sortTreeNode);
        sort(rhs.subNodes.begin(), rhs.subNodes.end(), sortTreeNode);


        if (equal(subNodes.begin(), subNodes.end(), rhs.subNodes.begin(), checkLevelTreeNode)) {
            auto Lh = subNodes.begin();
            auto Rh = rhs.subNodes.begin();

            while (Lh != subNodes.end()) {
                if (!(*Lh)->compare(*(*Rh)))
                    return false;
                Lh++; Rh++;
            }
        }
        else
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    ~TreeNode() {
        for (auto & Current : subNodes)
            delete Current;

        subNodes.clear();

        parent = nullptr;
    }

    vector<TreeNode*> subNodes;  // list of pointers to all childNodes of particular Node
    TreeNode* parent = nullptr;  // pointer to parent Node of this node
};

bool sortTreeNode(TreeNode* a, TreeNode* b) {
    return (a->data < b->data);
}

bool checkLevelTreeNode(TreeNode* a, TreeNode* b) {
    return a->data == b->data;
}


int main()
{
    int size1 = 3;
    int size2 = 3;

    TreeNode Main1 { 1 };
    TreeNode Main2 { 1 };

    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        TreeNode * ptr1 = new TreeNode{ i };
        TreeNode * ptr2 = new TreeNode{ size1 -1 -i };

        ptr1->parent = &Main1;
        Main1.subNodes.push_back(ptr1);

        ptr2->parent = &Main2;
        Main2.subNodes.push_back(ptr2);

        for (int j = 0; j < size2; j++) {
            TreeNode* ptr3 = new TreeNode{ j };
            TreeNode* ptr4 = new TreeNode{ size2 -1 -j };

            ptr3->parent = ptr1;
            ptr1->subNodes.push_back(ptr3);

            ptr4->parent = ptr2;
            ptr2->subNodes.push_back(ptr4);
        }
    }
    cout << "Main1\n";
    Main1.Print();
    cout << "Main2\n";
    Main2.Print();

    cout << "Compare: " << (Main1.compare(Main2) ? "True" : "False") << endl;

    cout << "Main1\n";
    Main1.Print();
    cout << "Main2\n";
    Main2.Print();

    return 0;
}
```

output

```
Main1
{ 0 1 2 }
{ 0 1 2 }
{ 0 1 2 }
{ 0 1 2 }
Main2
{ 2 1 0 }
{ 2 1 0 }
{ 2 1 0 }
{ 2 1 0 }
Compare: True
Main1
{ 0 1 2 }
{ 0 1 2 }
{ 0 1 2 }
{ 0 1 2 }
Main2
{ 0 1 2 }
{ 0 1 2 }
{ 0 1 2 }
{ 0 1 2 }
```